# Get the difference between two repos OR get only the lines from the last X commits

Tags: git, github

#### Context

So I'm trying to use [MOSS](https://theory.stanford.edu/~aiken/moss/) to compare a student's repo with a complete reference implementation that is (unfortunately) publicly available.

What we do is give students a base repo and then they fork from it and implement their own code. The problem is that previous years' finished repo's are online.

#### Current Situation

The way I have been checking their repo's for cheating so far is as follows:

1. Clone their repo's on my machine
2. Run moss on all files in their repo vs the complete implementation online
3. Sift through each potential match block and see if
   it's actually cheating or if it's a false positive* (see below)

#### The problem:

The problem is that because the base code is so massive, that at least 60% of any implementation is a match with the reference implementation. If I see something higher, I have to individually check each code block to see if it's part of the base code. Sometimes, I can't even remember if it's base code or not, so I take more time checking that. This entire process takes too long, and the class has scaled up very rapidly, so it's becoming infeasible to do this manually for each student.

### My question:

Is there a way, given a `base_repo` (the one we give to students), to basically do something of an equivalent to a set difference:

`student_repo = student_repo - base_repo`

or at the very least, if the commit history of a repo is something like:

```
commit c005 - "student commit finished assignment!"
commit c004 - "student commit finished second step"
commit c003 - "student first commit: finished first step"
commit c002 - "instructor base_code complete!"
commit c001 - "instructor base_code commit2"
commit c000 - "instructor base_code commit1"
```

can i get all the lines that were not from commits `c000`-`c002`? (to see *only* everything the students added)

If I have a technique to do so, I can also do the same with the online repos that students may be cheating from and compare the two in MOSS.

This way, I won't get any false positives in my MOSS results and can easily tell if the students copied code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Git CMD installed, you can obtain the full log through:

```
git log master
```

The one closest to what are wanting to do would be:

```
git log master --oneline
fc9c000 added some contextual information
1527000 2019-09-14 20:08:05 - Update
3e40000 2019-09-14 19:00:37 - Update
e800000 2019-09-14 18:55:40 - Tidy some parts of the code.
```

This format will give you hash, author and summary for each commit and save to csv (for windows):

```
git log master --pretty=tformat:"%h,%an,\"%s\"" > log.csv
```

If you like to see the full list of output and formats then have a look at this page:
https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do something like this.  I'll assume for the moment that your base repository always uses the same content, and that the last commit in your base repository (when abbrviated) is `c002`.

When you clone each repository, you can generate a diff between the original code and the student's code with `git diff c002`.  That will show you the changes (with context) that are specific to this user's implementation and differ in a standard diff format.

If you literally want only the lines that are added, changed, and removed, you can pass `-U0` and `git diff` will use no context lines.  The deletions will still be present, though; you can use something like the following:

```
git diff -U0 c002 | perl -ne 'unless (/^diff --git/../^@@/) { print if /^\+/; }'
```

That will include only the addition lines.

Comment: So this is really helpful, and I have used something similar to this before. But is it possible using the additions, to remove everything else in the files?

Comment: It isn't possible natively with Git, but you could process the diff output and write a different tree of files with only the additions, then upload that to MOSS.  This is a somewhat uncommon use case, so it isn't supported as a built-in feature.